# If IsError in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use something with similar functionality as Iferror(value, value_if_error) or Iserror(value) in VBA?

I tried to write:

```
If IsError(Cells(i, c) / curr) Then
'CODE BLOCK 1
else
'CODE BLOCK 2
end if
```

But VBA tells me that I have division by zero error when it tries to run the if-statement. It throws me into debug. But this is just the type of thing I want to trigger CODE BLOCK 1!

Comment: Why do you not just check if `curr` is 0 ?

Comment: But yes, VBA is notably bad at error handling.

Comment: There can be other types of errors as well, like there being text in the numerator. The easiest would be to just check for any error.

Comment: I figured I would try LINE1: On Error GoTo ErrCurr LINE2: Cells(i, c) = Cells(i, c) / instanceCurrency LINE3: On Error GoTo 0. But strangely the division by zero error isn't sent to the error handler. It triggers the debug. Any idea why?

Comment: Change your settings to `Tools>Options>General>Select 'Break on Unhandled Errors'`

Comment: The problem is that it breaks. I want it to go to the error handler.

Comment: I found the reason. There were some earlier GoTo statements in the code (written by another guy) that caused problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual way to handle this would be

```
i = 0
On Error Resume Next
n = 1 / i
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Handle error - code block 1
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' No error - code block 2

End If
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call all worksheet functions using `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(args)`

You could also try doing the calculation in a cell directly and query it's value. For example, very hacky:

```
Sub asdf()

    Dim ws As New Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim i As Double
    i = 0
    ws.Range("A2").Formula = "=iserror(A1 / " & i & ")"

    If ws.Range("A2").Value Then
        Debug.Print "Error caught"
    Else
        Debug.Print "No error"
    End If

End Subu
```

Comment: If Application.WorksheetFunctions.IsError(Cells(i, c) / curr) Then triggers "Object does't support this property or method".

Comment: +1. @user1283776 Its a typo, should be `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError`. Same with `IfError`, both should do what you asked.