# VBA code to put value in cell if there is error in other cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file where each cells shows value when button "Calculate" is clicked.

So, If any cell gets an error, I have to give another value into the main cell.

Is it possible to put predefined value in a input cell by VBA when error occurs in other cell? Input cell should also be free for manual entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If IsError in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562252/if-iserror-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, a range of cells is filled when the calculate button (a marco) is pressed. If anny of these cells in this range has an error, the main cell (whatever this is) has to get a different value..

Question 1: what does the main cell contain when there is no error? 
Question 2: how is the range filled? By the macro?

Assumption: if Q2 is correct, then the macro should handle the error and give the main cell a different value....

Comment: It seems like I shouldn't have to give a explanation again. Because, Your understanding is absolutely correct. However, to answer your questions, Main cell is a input in which value will be entered regularly so there will be a value always. For the question 2, range of cells updates exactly with a macro. So to finalise, when there is an error in cell, Input value will be taken from VBA which is defined. or if possible input cell can go back to previous value. But I haveno idea which is easier. This is only my 3rd excel project.

Comment: You can store the "previous value" in a variable when you have done processing/filling the cells and checked if there is an error. However, a feedback that there was an error would be nice I guess.

Comment: Can you give me any code example?

Sorry for the delayed comment.

Comment: This is not really an answer, more of an extended comment.